# White box seemingly overlays all content past a certain point on our website in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7, wordpress-theming

I'm banging my head against my desk trying to figure this out.  I've got a mac and no access to an IE7 machine so all I've found to do so far is use browserlab (slow) to see if any changes I'm making are helping.  So far, nothing I've done has made the white box covering the bottom half of the page up budge.

I'm in over my head a little with the site, I know it's rough around the edges, but damn, it works in other browsers fine!

If anybody could please take a look and give me a few clues I'd be VERY greatful.

Thanks.

http://www.arnoldsffc.com/

Comment: `"all I've found to do so far is use browserlab (slow) to see if any changes I'm making are helping"` - wow, that must be painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somehow down to the `height: 300px` rule on `#header`.

Removing that fixes IE7, and I didn't notice any changes in IE8 or Firefox.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/eyube4) *(with a version of the fix, works in IE7)*

I don't know the reason *why* this works, and I'm not going to dig for it unless you really want me to.

So you can (hopefully!) accept my answer faster, use this site to check it in IE7:

http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/
It's fast.

Answer (score 1):

What are all those stray `</div>` tags doing at the end of the page?  As far as I can tell, IE is upset mostly because the markup is invalid.

Comment: To add to this, check out the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arnoldsffc.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). I don't think it's the cause of this, but it's never a good idea to have mismatched tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out - http://www.onderhond.com/tools/ie6fixer/ , maybe it will fix it.